# Why use Vagrant as post-processor with Packer while building virtualbox OVA

Tags: vagrant, packer

I am new to Packer and I am building Virtualbox images with Packer. It works fine so far and I can build my VMs.

However, I am wondering why people are using Vagrant as post processor to build the OVA as in the example below :

```
"post-processors": [
    {
      "type": "vagrant",
      "compression_level": "9",
      "output": "debian-{{user `debian_version`}}-amd64_{{.Provider}}.box",
      "only": ["virtualbox-iso"]
    }
],
```

For me, the virtualbox-iso builder already provides an OVA file, so why use Vagrant after this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packer was mainly first introduced as a tool to build vagrant box. When vagrant became popular a while ago, it was not so easy to create your own box (you had tools such as Veewee or download existing box from http://www.vagrantbox.es)

so Packer came at first as a main replacement for Veewee; even though the framework was already in place to create **identical images** for dev.

Because most people are using packer with vagrant, you'll find this post-processor which will create the vagrant box (you can then publish this box on [atlas](https://app.vagrantup.com/boxes/search) or distribute internally, etc)

If you do not plan to use vagrant at all, but you only need the OVA virtual box VM, you of course do not use the vagrant box to be created. you'll loose the ability to work with vagrant and benefits from its feature, but thats another story

Answer (score 0):

You are misunderstanding the purpose of the [*vagrant post-processor*](https://www.packer.io/docs/post-processors/vagrant.html). It is used to create a [Vagrant box](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes.html) *from* the OVA, not to run Vagrant.

Comment: I surely have misanderstood the purpose of the vagrant post-processor. However, from articles on the internet, this post processor is often used even if the final goal is to have an OVA at the end. I was wondering the usefulness of doing so. In which case do we need to have a vagrant box from an OVA if want just want to have a virtualbox image ?